# Spring Cloud Sleuth is using same trace Id

Tags: spring, zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have enabled the sleuth in my application, and I started getting the log with traceId and spanId but I am getting the same traceId for all the various logs.

My input source is a message Listener, so it might be all handled with a single thread, so that would be a cause. Is there any way we force to use a new traceId?

I have tried `@NewSpan`, `Span span = this.tracer.newTrace().start();` etc with no benefit.

I am using version 2.0.0.RELEASE

```
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:jar:2.0.0.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: Can you check if the problem is still there with the latest snapshot? If that's the case can you upload a sample that replicates this problem?

Comment: Hi @MarcinGrzejszczak, I am outside with no code access, so I will try it first thing Monday morning, and I will upload the sample code. Thanks